# How can I refresh the property of observable array?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

```
    <div id="display" data-bind='foreach: stories'>
            <div class='story'>
                <div class="show_rait">
                    <button class="plus_btn" data-bind="click: rait++">plus</button>
                    <label data-bind="text: rait"></label>
                    <button class="minus_btn" data-bind="click: rait--">minus</button>
                </div>
                <div class='right'></div>
                <div class='title' data-bind='text: $data.title'></div>
                <div class='inside' data-bind='text: inside'></div>
            </div>
            </div>

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    //data
    self.stories = ko.observableArray([
    {title: "story", inside: "some story", rait: -1},
    {title: "story", inside: "Koko jambo", rait: -1},
    {title: "story", inside: "trali vali ", rait: -1},        
    {title: "4 story", inside: "some text": -1},
    {title: "5 story", inside: "yo", rait: -1}]),
```

Rait++ and Rait-- have to increment and decriment the rait. It works but just after reload. Can I refresh just this piece `<label data-bind="text: rait"></label>` or how can I fix this problem? Also I tried to make rait property observable `rait: ko.observable(-1)` but after click and refresh all template it return NaN.

Answer (score 0):

It´s just a guess, but please try this :

```
<button class="plus_btn" data-bind="click:function(){ rait++;rait.valueHasMutated();}">plus</button>
```

Comment: Just second variant is working, thank for you help, but it's not what I want. Label with rait show the correct result just after refresh all template. I need that text of label changes immediatly.

Comment: okay, valueHasMutated() explicitly says knockout to refresh the view, so i wonder it doesnt work for you

Comment: Is `rait` still an observable? If not, it won't update unless the whole list updates.

Comment: rait it's component of observable array, I tried to make it observable like this rait: ko.observable(-1) but after refresh it's return NaN